# Retrieving command line args in gas

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am struggling to find a way to retrieve first character of the first command line argument in GAS. To clarify what I mean here how I do it in NASM:

```
main:   
    pop ebx
    pop ebx
    pop ebx            ; get first argument string address into EBX register
    cmp byte [ebx], 45 ; compare the first char of the argument string to ASCII dash ('-', dec value 45)
    ...
```

EDIT: Literal conversion to AT&T syntax and compiling it in GAS won't produce expected results. EBX value will not be recognized as a character.

Comment: Do you want to use AT&T style syntax? Otherwise just use `.intel_syntax noprefix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out myself. Entry point should NOT be called `main`, but `_start`. Thanks Basile for a hint, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand why you want, in 2011, to code an entire application in assembly (unless fun is your main motivation, and coding thousands of assembly lines is fun to you).
And if you do that, you probably don't want to call the entry point of your program `main` (in C on Gnu/Linux, that function is called from crt0.o or similar), but more probably `start`.

And if you want to understand the detailed way of starting an application in assembly, read the [Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and the [Linux ABI supplement for x86-64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) and similar documents for your particular system.

Comment: This is more like a home work, I wrote some simple NASM CRC5 code. Now trying to convert it to GAS.